# Create user control for Message Dialog

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, user-controls, winrt-xaml

I want to create a user control for message dialog box so that depending on the requirement the UI of the message dialog changes. For example if I pass title, Message and type then depending on the type of message it should show that message dialog.
Type can be: Error, Warning, simple Message, etc. How can I achieve this?
The UI of the Custom Message Dialog should look as below when type is set as Error example:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a sample implementation [here](http://awaitableui.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/18667#139598) that uses the [Awaitable UI](http://awaitableui.codeplex.com/) approach (using async/await keywords to wait for UI events).

Answer (score 2):

This is surprisingly more difficult to accomplish than you think. The challenges lay in making sure the dialog remains asynchronous and in getting it in the visual tree. Gope already mentioned **CustomDialog** that's in the Callisto framework, but I found that to be very limiting. Instead, I followed this really great article that shows you how to make a general purpose dialog that can be used to display any user control:

**Creating a custom async dialog for your Win8 apps**
http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2012/11/12/Creating-a-custom-async-dialog-for-your-Win8-apps-Part-2-CustomDialog.aspx

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport

Comment: There is also a [Nuget pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncDialogs/) for this awesome dialog!  Install pack "AsyncDialogs"

Answer (score 0):

oh god you are asking a lot!

:)

okay do this way, i will guide you and you do your part:

create a class SysDialog : HtmlGenericControl

```
public SysDialog() {
 TagName = 'div';
}

public string Title {get;set;}
public string Message {get;set;}
public string MessageType {get;set;}

public SysDialog Render(){ 

HtmlGenericControl title = new HtmlGenericControl ();
title.TagName = "div";
HtmlGenericControl msg = new HtmlGenericControl ();
msg.TagName = "div";

title.InnerHTML = Title;
msg.InnerHTML = Message;
Controls.Add(title);
Controls.Add(msg);
title.Attritbues.Add("class", "title-" + MessageType);
msg.Attritbues.Add("class", "msg-" + MessageType);
Attritbues.Add("class", "sysdlg-" + MessageType);
return this;
}
```

Its just start point, you modify this code and enhace your message types and ass as many divs/buttons or whatever based on your message types.

Comment: Although I like the idea about combining CSS-classes and the Type I believe the question is about C#/XAML not HTML/Javascript...
Still, clever! :)

Comment: (doh) but he never mentioned the XAML thingy but tags. Anyway, thanks for liking the idea (dull)

Answer (score 0):

First you should look into Callisto and its CustomDialog (http://bit.ly/ILTyRn). Unfortunately it is a still a sealed class so you can either use its code or define an AttachedProperty for the dialog type. All you need besides that are 3 different Templates and a TemplateSelector that is checking for the DialogTypeProperty (You need to create such a Property - AttachedProp f.e.)

Hope that points you in the right direction. :)